# Unable to find soap 1.1 address

Tags: apex, soap, wsdl, wsdl2apex

When attempting to generate Apex from a 3rd party WSDL, I'm getting below error.

[image]

I noticed this has soap12:binding, I tried to change this to soap11. I still get the error message, and fails to generate Apex from WSDL.

I'm new to wsdl2apex, and trying to figure out what could help fix it.

Appreciate any help/thoughts to fix it.
Thanks.

Comment: In what way did you change it to SOAP 1.1? Did you regenerate the whole WSDL in the 1.1 format that the corresponding web service would support?

Comment: Hi @DanielBallinger thanks for your comment, Got no access to this 3rd party WSDL. Being new to this, I went through previously posted questions, downloaded the wsdl manually tried to replace it, not too sure if I'm on the right track.

Comment: Unfortunately you won't be able to modify a SOAP 1.2 binding into a SOAP 1.1 binding and successfully call it with the automated wsdl2apex tooling. If you have only limited requirements for the service you could try and replicate the requests with a raw HttpRequest.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two part with 
`<wsdl:port ..>..</wsdl:port>`
you can try delete part for soap12:
`` `<wsdl:port name="xxxSoap12" binding="tns:xxSoap12">
      <soap12:address location="http://xxx" />
</wsdl:port> `` `
It works for me